# How to prevent an Excel Workbook_Open event from firing when opened by VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I have a workbook that does some whizbang stuff when you open it. That's great and I want to keep it the way it is but I also want to share some of the internal functions with a VB.NET project that relates to this magic workbook.

My VB.NET application supersedes the functionality of the open event. So if a user opens the workbook in Excel I want the magic to occur. If I open that same workbook from my VB.NET application I want to suppress the Workbook_Open event so I can do the magic from VB.NET instead.

Is there a flag I can set before I call Open that will allow me to run macros from that workbook while also suppressing the open event?

VB.NET Code looks like this:

```
' Set up Excel
Dim excelApp As Application
Dim thisWorkbook As Workbook
Dim excelBooks As Workbooks

' Start Excel 
excelApp = New Application With
{
    .Visible = False  ' Ninja mode
}

' Open the workbook
excelBooks = excelApp.Workbooks
thisWorkbook = excelBooks.Open(My.Settings.ExcelFileName)

' Run the subroutine.
excelApp.Run("WhizBang", SecretVBNETMagicPassedInToExcel)

' Close the workbook and release the COM objects.
thisWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(thisWorkbook)
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelBooks)
excelApp.Quit() 
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp)
GC.Collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code you do not want to run is in the Workbook_Open event handler, you can disable events for the application before opening the workbook to prevent the handler code from being called.

```
excelApp.EnableEvents = False
```